# how to upload excel into database using java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

hi
i am  having one excel file which contains 15 columns and having   5000 recordes.
Now entering 5000 records manually into database is really a tough one.
instead i want to create a small java application which get input as excel file and just by clicking upload to database button it should be uploaded to DB.

any ideas? is there any jar?
please anybody guide me with example

Comment: Can't help you with an example. But, can tell you that you could use POI library to read XLS and process every row. http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: maybe you need to use the right tool for the job. Most databases come with an upload utility.

Answer (score 1):

You need a excel parser. The popular one is [POI Spreadsheet](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html). Another one is [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL you'll probably want to look at this: [Import Excel Data into MySQL in 5 Easy Steps](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html).

Otherwise checkout the [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to parse an Excel document. Then iterate over the cells and insert them into your database. See [Getting Started with JDBC](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/jdbc/) if you're not familiar with writing to a database. Search around online as well, there are all sorts of libraries and examples out there.

Without more details about what you're doing it's hard to make more than these general suggestions.